# How to make a dataframe from another dataframe, using the shape[] of the old dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, shapes

I have a dataframe with shape (18,1), each cell of this dataframe is with shape (27, 2000, 10). I want to make a new dataframe with shape (27, 18*10) that each cell consists of 2000 data.
I was trying to do like this, but I got error:
[This is how my dataframe looks like][1]
with shape (18,1).
I tried this code to make the new dataframe:

```
 for i in range(18):
    a= pd.DataFrame(((HC[i,0]).shape[2]) ,(18* HC[i,0].shape[0]))
```

andI get this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-20-3138007415b4> in <module>()
     19 HC
     20 for i in range(18):
---> 21    a= pd.DataFrame(((HC[i,0]).shape[2]) ,(18* HC[i,0].shape[0]))
     22 
     23 # print(a)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    356                 except ValueError as err:
    357                     raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 358             raise KeyError(key)
    359         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    360 

KeyError: (0, 0)
```

any idea how can I make the new dataframe?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cKqO.png

Comment: Try using `iloc` like this: `a= pd.DataFrame(((HC.iloc[i,0]).shape[2]) ,(18* HC.iloc[i,0].shape[0]))`  This is using iteger based location instead of label based location of a dataframe.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you for your response. I tried this too, but I got this error: `IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-15-d2926747cec8> in <module>()
      2 
      3 for i in range(18):
----> 4    a= pd.DataFrame(((HC_df.iloc[i,0]).shape[0]) ,(18* HC_df.iloc[i,0].shape[2]))
      5 
      6 print(a)

IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: HC.shape returns?

Comment: @ScottBoston HC.shape returns to (18,1) , but each cell of HC[i,0] returns to (27,2000,10). if you mean this.

Comment: Okay, what exactly are you trying to return with .shape[2]?  Pandas dataframes only return (r, c).  I not sure what shape[2].  The cells of HC have a dataframe or a numpy array?

Comment: @ScottBoston the cells are NumPy array. This is an EEG dataset, which I limited the original data to a new dataframe with 1c and 18rows. Each cell of this dataframe is included of (27,2000,10) data, that means 27 electrodes, 10 trials and 2000 time step for each of 18 cases. To analyze them, I wanted to make a new dataframe out of the cells' data, which looks like 27 rows and 18*10 columns, within 2000 data in each cell. But I couldn't make this out to my desire dataframe.